# TextCell and TextInputCell in GWT CellTable Header

Tags: gwt

I need a search box on the header of the GWT celltable.
I want both the Name of the header as well as the textbox in the header of the cell table.

|Header  1 | Header 2 |

|SEARCHBOX  | SEARCHBOX|

---

|    ROW 1

---

|    ROW 2

I can have any one textCell or TextInputCell in the header. But i'm not able to have both in the header.

can you help me plssss?

Thanks in advance.

Gnik.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented something like that however I run into a refresh problem. 
But if you don't refresh the CellTable after each keystroke there shouldn't be an issue. 
For implementation details check out this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422896/celltable-with-custom-header-containing-searchbox-and-focus-problem)

Basically you have to implement a custom AbstractCell (alternatively you could extend the TextinputCell and override the render method to output the header).