# Celltable with customheader with filter textbox into it(how to bind the filter textbox to keyUphandler

Tags: gwt, gwt-2.5

I have a requirement where i need to create the custom header which has textbox. When typing in it need to filter for the matching records.

By using following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422896/celltable-with-custom-header-containing-searchbox-and-focus-problem) ,I have created custom header. My CustomHeader class is

```
final public class ColumnHeaderFilterCell extends AbstractCell<String> {

interface Templates extends SafeHtmlTemplates {
@SafeHtmlTemplates.Template("<div >{0}</div>")
SafeHtml text(String value);

@SafeHtmlTemplates.Template("<div >
<input type=\"text\" value=\"\" name=\"{0}\"/></div>")
SafeHtml filter(String value);
}

private static Templates templates = GWT.create(Templates.class);

@Override
public void render(Context context, String value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
if (value == null) {
    return;
}

SafeHtml renderedText = templates.text(value);

sb.append(renderedText);

SafeHtml renderedFilter = templates.filter(value);
sb.append(renderedFilter);
}
}

*ColumnHeader class is* 


public static class ColumnHeader extends Header<String> {

private String name_;

public ColumnHeader(String name) {
    super(new ColumnHeaderFilterCell());
    this.name_ = name;
    //setHeaderStyleNames("columnHeader " + field);
}

@Override
public String getValue() {
    return name_;
}
}

*Adding a column as*

ColumnHeader docColHeader = new ColumnHeader("Documentaton");
cellTable.addColumn(documentaton, docColHeader);
```

Now my question is how can i add the addKeyUpHandler() event to the textbox which is celltable header?

I have implemented the filtering on celltable if the textbox outside somewhere else by using following  [link](http://pro.ingens.ru/2011/11/gwt-celltable-filtering_24.html) 
If iam able to pass the textbox object to the celltable header may be its helpful. i don't know how to pass.

Can anyone please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event handling within cells is not done through event handlers like with widgets, but at a lower level. See https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCustomCells#cell-onBrowserEvent

Comment: I have created a custom header for celltable. This custom header has combination of Textbox and checkbox. When I am type something in the textbox header i am able to capture and everything is smooth. But when i am clicking on the checkbox header, where its giving its value as **on** whether i have checking and unchecking the checkbox. 

Actually i should get true/false values. Why I am getting **on**?

How should i get the true/false values when check/unchecking the checkbox in the header?

Comment: com.google.gwt.dom.client.InputElement class has isChecked() method with taht i am able to get the value. My issue is solved.